# Hardware Configurations for softwares in production environment

Tags: tomcat, oracle11g, weblogic12c

I have to setup a production environment where i need to install - WebLogic 12.2.1 with 1 Admin server and  3 Managed server in a cluster, Apache Tomcat and Oracle Database Enterprise Edition 11g R2 with RAC in windows 8 R2 server.
Googled for knowing the hardware requirements of the mentioned software where i found some which created more confusion to me.

Do anyone can advice me on this or suggest me some link where I could refer the same?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what role should this production environment have. Should all parts - WLS/DB/Tomcat be placed on separate hardware machines? Or you can use ESX host to virtualize with VM's? Could you specify your business project scope? Especially- what type of HA do you need, how many external users will be conecting to WLS cluster, what type of system do you want to deploy on WLS cluster. Also what type of budget do you have... Please specify this.

In latest project architecture, related to Yours, build for OLTP system we ware proposing:
2 WLS hosts, 2 RAC hosts, 1 Tomcat LB host- all hardware machines: dell blade PowerEdge M630 Xeon E5-2637 v3, 256 GB RDIMM, 2x300 SAS 12GB/s.
On all machines: Vmware ESX, administrated by Vsphere operations manager

For RAC hosts we were using external matrix - for ASM installation. On hardware hosts - Oracle Linux 7 with one active instance on each.